# Facing error in firebase authentication (build.gradle)

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, build.gradle

[error description with error code line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mptZe.png)

[full code of build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IM4C.png)

I'm facing a puzzling issue while attempting to run my Flutter Android project using the flutter run command. The project was working fine before, but suddenly, I'm encountering the following error that mentioned on top.

I'm running out of ideas on how to resolve this issue. Could there be something I'm missing or a step I should take to fix this? Has anyone else encountered a similar problem? Any assistance or guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Which flutter version are you using?  run  `flutter --version` ?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.